# Adding sub total with query in active report

Tags: sql, vb6, activereports

I need to make some sub total in `Active reports` with `vb.6`, and the report contain each rowbased on `KDKRY` such this:

[image: Active report total]

How can I sum the 'Hour' according to the `KDKRY` so I can put it in 'Total Hours' Fields

I Make that report with this query :

```
select A.KDKRY, A.NMKRY, E.NMTOW,B.NMSTOW, SUM(C.HSTOW)JAM, 
COUNT(C.TGLWORK)MDAY, SUM(D.THSTOW)TOT
from TBL_KRY A, TBL_STOW B, TBL_DTSHEET C, TBL_HDTSEET D, TBL_TOW E
Where E.KDTOW = C.KDTOW and A.KDKRY = D.KDKRY And A.CJABATAN = 'OFFICER TEKNIS'
And C.KDHDTS = D.KDHDTS And B.KDSTOW = C.KDSTOW and C.TGLWORK between
'01.10.2017' and '31.10.2017'
group by A.KDKRY, A.NMKRY, E.NMTOW, B.NMSTOW
```

I already try summary with activereports but it doesnt work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your `GroupHeader1` section has its `DataField` set to `KDKRY`, place a `Field` control in corresponding `GroupFooter1` section and set control's properties like this:

```
DataField:       JAM
SummaryFunction: 0 - ddSFSum
SummaryGroup:    GroupHeader1
SummaryType:     3 - ddSMSubTotal
```